# Semiconductor Database for damage to electronics

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, semiconductors

My colleague, who has experience with EMP (electromagnetic pulse) analysis, mentioned a database for electronics (IC, discrete circuits, semiconductors devices) that contained the information on the "measured" damage level.  These values usually exceeded the maximum ratings which can be found on the part's datasheet.

Is anyone familiar with this database? He does not remember anymore details and I am hoping someone else on here can point me where to find it.

Comment: Why? The manufacturer won't guarantee operation outside the maximum ratings, you shouldn't expect it regardless of whether someone has tested a few of them or not.

Comment: @Finbarr Sometimes you're forced to use components outside of their spec range, like electronics that are used downhole in oil wells at much higher than abs max junction temperature, or commercial components in space.  In that case I can see why you would want to know actual failure points vs. what the manufacturer specifies.  Of course if the part fails you're on your own.

Comment: So, this analysis will include margins from the damage level (at least 6 dB). There is no plan to operate at these levels. This may be irrelevant but the electronics will be powered-off when the threat occurs and the threat is common-mode.

Comment: There is a test called TTD (Test To Destruction) that some semiconductor manufacturers use to run for automotive. These parameters were not guaranteed. I do not know if they do it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is this:

Gage, Byron P. EMP Electronic Analysis Handbook. BOEING CO SEATTLE WA, 1973.

The information I am interested is located in Appendix D.

Typing in the title phrase in Google Scholar helped me locate it and other (valuable) resources

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=EMP+Susceptibility+Threshold+Handbook&btnG=